Could not find a package configuration file provided by "controller_manager"
error info:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"controller_manager" with any of the following names:
controller_managerConfig.cmake
controller_manager-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
I exec this:
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-controller_manager
And I checked controller_manager is installed :
locate controller_managerConfig.cmake /opt/ros/noetic/share/controller_manager/cmake/controller_managerConfig.cmake
but it still compile failed.
